# Top Navigation Dojo widget

Tags: dojo, customization

Please find the attached image @
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?0db7e494ad.jpg

We would like to achieve similiar functionality using Dojo widgets. Can someone please suggest the best widgets that we should extend for achieving this. For example on hover on Tools shows the second level of navigation, which in turn can contain sublevels. On click on certain links in this sub levels should open a Dialog widget.
I'm new to Dojo world. Can someone please help me in implementing this.

Thanks,
Manoj

Answer (score 2):

There's a http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/MenuBar widget... it looks pretty different than your screenshot but I suppose it's just a difference of CSS settings.